# How create multiplies select with inner join in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want create that query

```
SELECT * FROM `books` INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `authors` GROUP by `author_id`) as variable ON variable.`id` = `books`.`id` INNER JOIN `student` ON `student`.`id` = variable.`id` WHERE (`books`.`id` = '1');
```

For the question, of course, the request itself is slightly changed, but that's not the point. Can you please help me to make this kind of request in `Ruby on Rails` style

I tried, but it's a bit not what I want ... I have to do `INNER JOIN (Select ... )`

```
Book.select('*').joins(author: :student).where("`books`.`id` = '1'").group("author.author_id")
```

Comment: Are you sure your example SQL is correct? You're saying the column `author.id` should be comparable to `books.id` and to `student.id`? If that is correct, could you elaborate on the database design that leads to that situation? Also, please include the SQL that the activerecord code is generating for comparison with what you want. Finally, is this definitely a `ruby-on-rails-3` question (that version of Rails is 10+ years old) or is it just that you are using ruby version 3?

Comment: Removed ruby 3. No, the database is different, there are other columns and other data, it's just a made-up request due to the fact that I can't expose true tables and columns. But my `SELECT` it WORKS fine, but I would like this `SELECT` to be coded in pure Rails. Of course, I can make it not pure and it will work (checked) but I want it to be with pure Rails
Could you help me make the CLEAN rails code for the request I submitted? I'll change the variables myself

Answer (score 0):

While your SQL does not appear to make any logical sense you can construct this query as follows:

```
author_table = Author.arel_table

author_sub_query = Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(
  author_table
    .project(author_table[Arel.star])
    .group(author_table[:author_id]), 'variable')

author_join = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
   author_sub_query,
   author_sub_query.create_on(author_sub_query[:id].eq(Book.arel_table[:id])))

student_join = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(
   Student.arel_table,
   author_sub_query.create_on(Student.arel_table[:id].eq(author_sub_query[:id])))

Book
  .select(Arel.star)
  .joins(author_join,student_join)
  .where(id: 1)
```

Which will produce:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `books` 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT `authors`.* FROM `authors` GROUP BY `authors`.`author_id`) `variable` 
    ON `variable`.`id` = `books`.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `students` 
    ON `students`.`id`= `variable`.`id`  
WHERE 
  `books`.`id` = 1
```

That being said I have no idea what you are trying to do with this but if the intent is to eager load this data, you could try making these changes to the above:

```
author_sub_query = Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(
  author_table
    .project(author_table[Arel.star])
    .group(author_table[:author_id]), Author.table_name)
Book
  .joins(author_join,student_join)
  .eager_load(author: :student)
  .where(id: 1)
```

Comment: yes thanks i will try 
it makes no sense, since the names have been changed, etc., etc., since I can’t put the real table and real names in public access, so I replaced

Comment: @kaserr I certainly understood that the information is obfuscated (although in the future I would recommend atleast trying to make it logical). I am hopeful that you can glean what you need from this as I obviously cannot solve your actual issue without actual information.